# Python - How to convert datetime data using toordinal considering the time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's assume that I have the following data:

`25/01/2000 05:50`

When I convert it using `datetime.toordinal`, it returns this value:

`730144`

That's nice, but this value just considers the date itself. I also want it to consider the hour and minutes (05:50). How can I do it using datetime?

EDIT:

I want to convert a whole Pandas Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [ordinal date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date) is by definition only considering the year and day of year, i.e. its resolution is 1 day.

You can get the microseconds / milliseconds (depending on your platform) from epoch using

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('25/01/2000 05:50', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').timestamp()
```

---

for a `pandas` series you can do

```
s = pd.Series(['25/01/2000 05:50', '25/01/2000 05:50', '25/01/2000 05:50'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s) # make sure you're dealing with datetime instances
s.apply(lambda v: v.timestamp())
```

Comment: `s.apply(lambda v: v.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))` - the documentation for datetime is useful for figuring out the format string https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 3.x. You can get date with time in seconds from 1/1/1970 00:00

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.today()  # Get timezone naive now
seconds = dt.timestamp()
```